# Shortest path of combinations to reach given total

Tags: excel, vba

I need come up with the shortest path to my problem. I am not a programmer by trade by any means. I am trying to do this in excel. I have read several other instances of this problem on here, but I have not found an answer that would help me. Can anyone help me with a solution that I can implement in excel?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYPcz.png]

I have 6 different spacers. I need to have a quick way to determine the optimal combination (least amount spacers) of these spacers to reach my target size. You may use multiple of each spacer if necessary.

```
White (51mm)
Black (44mm)
Blue (38mm)
Green (32mm)
Purple (26mm)
Orange (13mm)
```

Example:

```
Target - 83mm
Optimal solution: White - 1; Green - 1
Excel Solver solution: Blue - 1; Green - 1; Orange - 1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like it may be a homework problem. If so, please read [this guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), and post your work so far. What is your specific problem? What have you tried? What was the result? Posting that information makes it easier (indeed, feasible) for others to help.

Comment: @Evan, thank you. It is not a homework problem. It is something that I am doing at work. I have tried several calculators provided, but the problem I am running to is that all of the calculators do not allow duplicate numbers to be used. Example, when I try to find the combinations that make 132 mm with my numbers listed above, I receive no combinations because it is using 44 mm "Black" spacer three times. I want to be able to input 132 and it list that I need to use 3 Black spacers. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If all spacer sizes can only be positive, then one solution might be to work backwards from `target` and keep subtracting "all combinations" of spacer sizes until your subtraction yields `0` (which indicates that a solution has been reached).

Problems with the code below:

- Basically brute force and no intelligence.
- High space complexity, so you may get an "out of memory" error when search space exceeds your system's limitations.
- Currently the code uses the indexes and elements of the arrays to work out if a solution has been found, but this also requires that the array contiguously store all results (even those which are being/will be skipped).
- An alternative approach might be to store both the element and the index within the array, which would mean the index-element pairs could be filtered after each iteration (to remove elements which won't yield a solution). Doing this means you need to store two pieces of information (the element and the index) rather than just one (the element), so the initial cost is higher. However, as the deeper you go into the search space, the more beneficial this approach may become.
- Another approach might be to read/write arrays from/to the disk in chunks -- so that it is not necessary at any given time to store the entire in memory. This is a memory-friendlier approach, but would likely require more code to be written (unless there is an existing library/module available).
- Since all indexes (used to access array elements) are of type `Long`, it is possible to receive an overflow error (say if the array needs to contain more than 2147483647 elements). This could be improved by declaring all index variables as type `Double` instead of `Long` (although the time required to cover a search space that large might be the primary issue in such a scenario).
- No canonicalisation, meaning code might try `target - white spacer size - black spacer size`, and then later try `target - black spacer size - white spacer size`; even though the result would be the same for both attempts. (In other words, the code tries a lot of combinations it doesn't need to.)
- Code tries to skip combinations where the previous iteration has already yielded a value that would make traversing the current path any further a waste of time (e.g. if previous iteration yielded a negative number, or a number less than the minimum spacer size). However, it does so at the cost of storing that previous iteration's result. Moreover, the code performs all these checks again on the next iteration (which is expensive as the number of checks grows with each iteration).
- No periodic `DoEvents`, so Excel may become unresponsive if the solution exists deeper/further within the search space.
- Last point is output-related. When writing the solutions back to the sheet, the code does not clear the cells. This means that if this time there are fewer solutions than last time, not all of last time's solutions will be overwritten. (Maybe you could programmatically clear the cells before running the code.)

You will need to change the worksheet name and cell references in `TryToSolve` procedure, but the code itself is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function ConvertRangeToArrayOfLongs(ByVal someRange As Range) As Long()
    Dim inputArray As Variant
    inputArray = someRange.Value

    Dim outputArray() As Long
    ReDim outputArray(1 To UBound(inputArray, 1))

    Dim arrayIndex As Long
    For arrayIndex = LBound(outputArray, 1) To UBound(outputArray, 1)
        outputArray(arrayIndex) = CLng(inputArray(arrayIndex, 1))
    Next arrayIndex

    ConvertRangeToArrayOfLongs = outputArray
End Function

Public Sub TryToSolve()
    ' Subroutine needs better name.

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Mine was on Sheet1, change to whatever your sheet is called.

    Dim target As Long
    target = sourceSheet.Range("A3") ' Mine was in cell A3, change to wherever yours is

    Dim spacerSizesRange As Range
    Set spacerSizesRange = sourceSheet.Range("D3:D8") ' Mine were in this range. Change to wherever yours are

    Dim spacerSizes() As Long
    spacerSizes = ConvertRangeToArrayOfLongs(spacerSizesRange)

    Dim spacerQuantities As Collection
    Set spacerQuantities = GetMinimumSpacerQuantities(target:=target, spacerSizes:=spacerSizes)

    If spacerQuantities.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No solution found within the search space." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " (If implementation is correct, then there is no combination of current spacer sizes which can produce the current target value.)"
        End
    End If

    ' The bit below doesn't clear any previous writes. So if there are fewer results than last time,
    ' not all of last time's values will be overwritten.
    Dim writeIndex As Long
    For writeIndex = 1 To spacerQuantities.Count
        spacerSizesRange.Offset(0, writeIndex).Value = Application.Transpose(spacerQuantities(writeIndex)) ' TRANSPOSE can only handle ~65k
    Next writeIndex
End Sub

Private Function GetMinimumSpacerQuantities(ByVal target As Long, ByRef spacerSizes() As Long) As Collection
    ' This function needs a better name.

    Dim countOfSpacers As Long
    countOfSpacers = UBound(spacerSizes) ' Assumed to be 1-based

    Dim smallestSpacer As Long ' Assumed to be whole number
    smallestSpacer = Application.RoundUp(Application.Min(spacerSizes), 0)

    Dim iterationLimit As Long ' Assuming no negative spacer sizes, solution must exist within this search space.
    iterationLimit = Application.RoundUp(target / smallestSpacer, 0)

    Dim outputCollection As Collection
    Set outputCollection = New Collection

    Dim iterationIndex As Long
    For iterationIndex = 1 To iterationLimit

        Dim currentResults() As Long
        Dim arrayToSubtract() As Long

        If iterationIndex > 1 Then
            arrayToSubtract = currentResults()
        Else
            arrayToSubtract = GetInitialisedNumericArray(lengthOfArray:=1, valueToInitialiseWith:=target)
        End If

        Const FLAG_VALUE As Long = -1
        currentResults = GetInitialisedNumericArray(lengthOfArray:=countOfSpacers ^ iterationIndex, valueToInitialiseWith:=FLAG_VALUE)

        Dim writeIndex As Long
        writeIndex = 0 ' Needs resetting each iteration, otherwise index will be incorrect or out of bounds

        Dim subtractionIndex As Long
        For subtractionIndex = LBound(arrayToSubtract) To UBound(arrayToSubtract)
            If arrayToSubtract(subtractionIndex) >= smallestSpacer Then
                Dim spacerIndex As Long
                For spacerIndex = 1 To countOfSpacers
                    writeIndex = writeIndex + 1
                    currentResults(writeIndex) = arrayToSubtract(subtractionIndex) - spacerSizes(spacerIndex)

                    If currentResults(writeIndex) = 0 Then
                        MaybeAddArrayToCollection someCollection:=outputCollection, someArray:=TranslateLoopStateToSpacerIndexes(writeIndex:=writeIndex, iterationIndex:=iterationIndex, countOfSpacers:=countOfSpacers)
                    End If
                Next spacerIndex
            Else
                writeIndex = writeIndex + countOfSpacers
            End If
        Next subtractionIndex

        If outputCollection.Count > 0 Then Exit For
    Next iterationIndex

    Set GetMinimumSpacerQuantities = outputCollection

End Function

Private Function TranslateLoopStateToSpacerIndexes(ByVal writeIndex As Long, ByVal iterationIndex As Long, ByVal countOfSpacers As Long) As Long()
    ' If you have the "writeIndex" for a particular iteration,
    ' you can figure out which spacer index (and therefore which
    ' spacer) the "writeIndex" represents via modular arithmetic.
    '
    ' Given the current iteration's "writeIndex", to figure out
    ' the previous iteration's "writeIndex":
    '       ROUNDUP( currentWriteIndex / countOfSpacers )
    '
    ' Do the above in a loop (with iterationIndex declining) and keep track of
    ' each spacerIndex encountered.

    Dim calculatedWriteIndex As Long
    calculatedWriteIndex = writeIndex ' Can't calculate first time around. We already know it.

    Dim outputArray() As Long
    ReDim outputArray(1 To countOfSpacers)

    Dim i As Long ' Needs better name, but also kind of irrelevant/unreferenced elsewhere.
    For i = iterationIndex To 1 Step -1
        Dim calculatedSpacerIndex As Long
        calculatedSpacerIndex = ((calculatedWriteIndex - 1) Mod countOfSpacers) + 1 ' -1 + 1 to return a 1-based index

        outputArray(calculatedSpacerIndex) = outputArray(calculatedSpacerIndex) + 1

        calculatedWriteIndex = Application.RoundUp(calculatedWriteIndex / countOfSpacers, 0)
    Next i

    TranslateLoopStateToSpacerIndexes = outputArray

End Function

Private Function GetInitialisedNumericArray(ByVal lengthOfArray As Long, ByVal valueToInitialiseWith As Long) As Long()
    ' lengthOfArray is expected to be 1-based.
    ' I chose Long as return type since spacer sizes in example only seem to include whole numbers.

    Dim outputArray() As Long
    ReDim outputArray(1 To lengthOfArray)

    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(outputArray) To UBound(outputArray)
        outputArray(index) = valueToInitialiseWith
    Next index

    GetInitialisedNumericArray = outputArray
End Function

Private Sub MaybeAddArrayToCollection(ByVal someCollection As Collection, ByRef someArray() As Long)

    Dim toJoin() As String
    ReDim toJoin(LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray))

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
        toJoin(i) = CStr(someArray(i))
    Next i

    Dim canonicalKey As String
    canonicalKey = Join$(toJoin, "|$%__|")

    On Error Resume Next
    someCollection.Add Item:=someArray, Key:=canonicalKey
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

For the example posted in your question, I think the code should work okay. But if your actual data is much larger, be aware that this code will not scale well. Also, you are more likely to encounter memory issues if:

- number of spacers increase
- ratio between `target` and minimum spacer size increases

since these factors also dictate the size of the search space.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will give this a try. I think the highest number I would be using right now would be around 300. Would I experience an error with this?

Comment: This works pretty good. I have a question for you though. What is the logic to decide which option when there are multiple answers? My example here is 64. For our purpose, we would most likely use two green spacers. The code chose one white and one orange. Is there anything that can be done here?

Comment: @BrianGundling, currently the code will return the first solution it encounters. The first solution it encounters will likely be determined by the original order in which the spacers were listed (I think). To prove this, try moving "Green" above "White", enter `target` as `64`. Does the code then return "2 green" instead of "1 white + 1 orange". Let me ask you your question, why is "2 green" a more satisfactory solution to you? Is it arbitrary or is there some logic to it (e.g. smallest number of distinct spacers)?

Comment: If I put Green above White it does select 2 green. The logic to it is that it would be easier for us to use 2 green spacers rather than one white and one orange. I think it would be difficult for this to be decided by this tool. Let me ask you another question. Is it possible to have all possible combinations populate in a table for the given target so I can see a list of all possibilities and select the most feasible? This would help in the situation where we are maybe out of a certain size spacer.

Comment: @BrianGundling I think it's possible if you want "all possible combinations" of only the minimum number of spacers (and not "all possible combinations" for all number of spacers). It should just be a case of moving the exit logic to the outermost iteration loop, maybe assigning a Boolean flag/variable inside the innermost loop (to indicate that at least one solution has been found and that this will be the last iteration), and storing all solutions within a collection. But I don't have time at the moment to do this

Comment: if you can help me when you do have time, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @BrianGundling, have edited my answer. I think you should get a bunch of spacer quantities written to the sheet. However, the code does not clear the write area between runs, so (depending on whether the current run has more solutions than the previous run) it's possible for solutions from previous runs to remain alongside the current run's solutions. Hope that makes sense and hope the code works for you.